# jQuery .getJSON not running with flask app

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, getjson

I have a flask application that I am trying to send some json to the browser and render it. But the line with `$.getJSON()` is not running. The jist of which is below:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index_html():

    data = {"this":"is", "just":"a test"}

    return render_template('index.html', data=data)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='jquery-3.5.1.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='leaflet/leaflet.js')}}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='leaflet/leaflet.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='app.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <h1>My test that doesn't work</h1>
    <div id="llmap"></div>

    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='app.js')}}"></script>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
console.log("before")

$.getJSON("/", function(data){
    console.log("during")
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});

console.log('after')
```

**Console OUTPUT**

```
before
after
```

Even if my data were somehow messed up, i'd expect at least to see

```
before
during
after
```

What am I not understanding here, why isn't `getJSON()` firing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using

```
return render_template('index.html', data=data)
```

You need to return ONLY data when you call the `.getJSON` function. simple

```
return data
```

should work. Because getJSON doesn't allow POST request you'll have to add one more route

```
@app.route('/')
def index_html():
   return render_template('index.html')
@app.route("/getjson")
def json():
   data = {"this":"is", "just":"a test"}
   return data
```

and change your `getJSON` request to

```
$.getJSON("/getjson", function(data){
    console.log("during")
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```